# How to study for the exams which are mathematical in approach but subjective in nature?

Tags: masters, undergraduate, exams

Predominantly whenever we are to face objective questions we generally tend to practice more and more objective question papers and sort of "remember the mistakes that we make while solving them".  However when it comes to subjective papers this approach doesn't seem to work for me anymore.  The more subjective questions I study the more I tend to deviate from whatever I need to retain for the approach.  Any suggestion about this will be highly appreciated.  I am particularly speaking with regard to semester examination of an Undergrad/Postgraduate course in Material Science & Engineering.

Comment: Could you give an example of the kind of course or exam you're wondering about?

Comment: The exam is predominantly a semester examination and the course is an undergraduate/postgraduate course in Material Science and Engineering.

Comment: It's hard for me to understand why a course in Material Science and Engineering is subjective.

Comment: Do you feel the questions are more subjective because you will be asked to synthesize information or do more design work?

Comment: Is is sort of like "How does concrete make you feel?"

Comment: @mkennedy It is asked to synthesize information which makes it all the more boring.

Comment: @JohnColeman Not really it asked questions like "Why is one particular dislocation glissile and the other sessile?"Justify/Substantiate.

Comment: Perhaps by "subjective" you simply mean "not explicitly computational".

Comment: @JohnColeman Absolutely correct.You just read my mind.

Comment: I don't know why you find such questions "boring". Computers can compute stresses, but they can't yet synthesize information in any genuinely conceptual way. You just need to show that your understanding of material science goes beyond what can by easily programmed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96183/discussion-between-gateprep-and-john-coleman).

Comment: Thank you for a good laugh! As an MSE PhD, you chose an example subject that could easily be held up as the perfect reason to ‘get a feel for’ what might happen. If you doubt me, find a copy of Hirth and Lothe’s book on dislocations and see just how mind boggling hard it is to try to calculate almost anything to do with dislocations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Learning math, science and engineering is to a certain extent about learning a collection of computational techniques that one can improve at by rote practice - integrating, differentiating, solving equations etc. But to a much larger extent it is about acquiring a conceptual understanding of the key ideas and concepts of the science you are being taught. This is a higher lever skill, and one that is ultimately much more important.

What you call “subjective” questions are precisely those questions that are designed to test your *understanding*. They are the questions that, ever since I started teaching, I have been hearing students (even well-intentioned, hard-working, eager to learn students) describe as “trick questions”, “unfair”, “not in the book”, “impossible to study for”, and so on. They are the questions that students dread and loathe and complain about and seek to find ways to avoid and bluff their way through. They are the questions that really test whether you have learned the main thing we wanted you to learn.

To be fair, subjective questions are indeed hard, and I completely sympathize with your frustration about them. They are characterized by the fact that there is no mechanical practice procedure, like “solve X problems from section Y in the book”, that is guaranteed to prepare you for them. Learning how to study for them is probably the single most valuable skill a student can hope to learn in their time at university. If you have learned how to study for subjective questions, it means you have learned how to learn, and that’s a wonderful thing to know.

So how *do* you study for them? In some sense that’s something each person has to discover for themselves. But in another sense the answer is blindingly obvious: you study the material, and you think about it. That’s it! But what I mean is *really really* study the material, and *really* think about it: that is, you think critically about each and every sentence of each and every section in the book/lecture notes and each and every thing the instructor said, trying to identify what conceptual meaning it is trying to tell you. You try to probe into every nook and cranny of the theory by criticizing it, and asking “what if” questions and “does this make sense?”, and reading Wikipedia and textbooks and watching online videos. You solve problems, and solve more problems, then go back to the theoretical part of the textbook and read it again and think about it in the context of the problems you solved. And watch more videos and read more books and forums and talk to your friends about the material. Etc etc. - note that this process has no natural end because no one understands everything, not even your professors. But at some point you’ll probably feel like you understand things at a reasonably good level for the exam you are about to take.

And then you move on to the next subject and start all over again. :-)

Comment: By solving more and more problems do you mean the computational part of simply the subjective ones?

Comment: @gateprep - he means actually think about the material. What about a material influences what? If a dislocation is glissile in an fcc material, how does it behave in bcc? OK, how about hcp, what is different? Monoclinic? At the heart of it, what factors do you need to consider, and why, to attack the problem in some arbitrary material? You can’t memorize and plug-and-chug through real world problems (or at least not at the salary point of a materials engineer).

Comment: @gateprep both. Try to think holistically about all aspects of the material, and solving any sorts of problems you can get your hands on - even invent your own problems. Solving a computational problem might also reach you something conceptual if you think about the meaning of what you are doing, and conversely a subjective problem might help you think of a trick that will be useful in doing computations. The distinction between the two types of problems is in any case a bit arbitrary, and many problems will be somewhere in the middle between those two categories.